# Set ProgressIndicator Size in java fx

Tags: progress-indicator

I cann't able to Set ProgressIndicator PrefSize in latest java 8 b120 version  In Linux (UBUNTU)  Version only..

i wants to Know whether its an Bug or it may be fixed in latest Versions..

Please Let me know Regarding this issue

Comment: We are gonna need a Little more on that. What IDE are you using? Are you writing FXML or Java code for the User Interface?

Comment: We are using Eclipse Juno  IDE and then we are developing in JAva Fx in java code

Comment: In which Container Nodes is your ProgressIndicator? Try looking at the sizes of these for errors.

Comment: As am setting my progressIndicator in VBOX component